# Parsing field name using Crystal Reports

Tags: parsing, crystal-reports

I have a customer who really wants to keep a very long naming convention during a migration to a new database. The new database uses Crystal Reports for reporting. I have gotten an ok to shorten the naming convention somewhat to "shortened name-date" with all of the other pertinent information parsed out into new fields.

However, one of the users who does a lot of the reporting has now said that one of the most tedious parts of her job was parsing out the old names so she could have a simple, high level, parent name for executive reports. With the new naming convention, she will still need to parse the field to get just the shortened name as her executive-level parent name. If I can't manage to get the ok to drop the date from this field, can Crystal reports be used to parse the field at the "-" similar to parsing the data using Excel? What I'm looking for is that her reports would have a formula that generates the executive-level short name behind the scenes so she doesn't have to think about it.

The date already exists in a date field, so parsing out the date from the name would not change other report functionality. Ideally, I would want to enter the data already separated out and concatenate fields per each user's particular needs, but I may not be able to do. Any info would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the long data field(s) looks like and what you want the parsed field to look like? A before and after :)

Comment: provide an example on how data looks like and how want to look like

Comment: Thanks, yes, here's an example: 
-Previous database event name: "XYZ Conference - 10/12/2014 - at the ABC Event Center - with John, Jill, and Joe - A Look into Biofilms" 
-User would use Text to Columns to get "XYZ Conference" for her report.

-New database better but same issue, field name is now: "XYZ Conference - 10/12/2014"
-She would like Crystal Reports to parse the field for her so the output in is simply "XYZ Conference"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this...

```
Split({fieldname},"-")[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. It'll be a bit before I can try this, but thank you in advance, and I will let you know if my customer is satisfied with the result.